# How do you get a Drupal webform in Gatsby (React)

Tags: reactjs, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I am planning to build a Drupal 8 site fully decoupled using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) (React). So I will use Drupal only to structure (Content types, paragraphs), enter and update all the content and data and use React (and Gatsby) for the frontend.

The website also needs a (simple) form. I will use the [webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) for this.

But how do you get a Drupal form in Gatsby (React) and after submitting send all completed fields to the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an extremely simple form, consider hosting your Gatsby site (for free) on Netlify and use Netlify Forms. Add any fields to your form (Captcha is a good idea too) and just add the Netlify tag to the form itself and Netlify will store it for you in their admin panel.

```
<form name="contact" method="POST" data-netlify="true">
```

Cheack out https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/

Answer (score 0):

You can access a Webform from React via jsonapi by addding the Webform to a Webform node.

In "Add content" select content type "Webform", then select the name of the form from the dropdown below the WYSIWYG editor, publish the node and record the ID.

The request will look something like this:

```
http://dev.local.com/jsonapi/node/webform?filter[nodeID][condition][path]=drupal_internal__nid&filter[nodeID][condition][value]=177007
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Gatsby plugin called [Gatsby Drupal Webform](https://github.com/oikeuttaelaimille/gatsby-drupal-webform) that makes it possible to expose forms made using Webform module in Drupal 8. You will also need module [Gatsby Webform Backend](https://www.drupal.org/project/react_webform_backend) as dependency in Drupal.

Answer (score -1):

Crazy :) Sounds like an early adopter approach. Gatsby is great for static content but when it comes to dynamic (including forms, submissions, error validation) then good luck as we won't see you for a loooong loooing time until you master secret JS JEDI knowledge... see you in a few years :)